# Difference between calling __doPostBack and Click Event of an asp button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am using __doPostback of a button control and it will take some time to complete the db operations. I am using it in an update panel and  I am getting an issue from IE that it will say 
 Stop running this script.

May I know what is the issue ?
I think it may be due to __doPostBack. Previously it is direclty calling the Click Event. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it triggering the button click handler when you call doPostback()

Comment: Yes I am calling button click and it will do some db operations

Answer (score 0):

Check your User Agent string. This same thing happened to me one time and I realized it was because I was testing out some pages as "googlebot". The JavaScript that is generated depends on knowing what the user agent is.

From http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=tr&comments_parentId=160492&forumId=1:

> To reset your user agent string type about:config into the location
>   bar and press enter. This brings up a list of preferences. Enter
>   general.useragent into the filter box, this should show a few
>   preferences (probably 4 of them). If any have the status user set,
>   right-click on the preference and choose Reset

Comment: How this solution will help me?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the 'Script taking too long' (all browsers have some form or another of this) message in browsers is relatively simple. You just have to make sure the browser knows you have not created an endless loop or recursion. And the easiest way to do is is to just give the browser a breather in between long running tasks.

have a look at this solution

http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/03/04/How-to-prevent-Stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers

Comment: i didn't get anything. can u pls tell me the logic behind it ?

Comment: basically you have to use the javascirpt SetTimeOut function to set a time out on you java-script call(in your case the js that calls the postback)

Comment: when i added set timeout() then also IE shows the message. What I am doing is from javascript I am calling __doPostback(button,''); . so this will triggers a btnClick defined and it may take time depends on data. Also this things are inside a update panel. This is actually my problem. I got a solution by fixing it using editing registry but it is not practically possible, because we need to use this in all clients who  may face this issue.